# The application does not read a downloaded Room database file until I delete the additional -wal and -shm files

Tags: java, android, android-room

The process so far:

I made a database file which I uploaded to the Firebase storage, from which I download the file to the data folder of the application in the device. Now while accessing the file through the Room database, the table is shown as empty.

I tried different ways to solve this and finally I found the issue to be the files that the Room database automatically generates with the -wal and -shm endings. The main database file which is generated is overwritten when downloading the file from the Firebase storage so that is not an issue. After deleting the -wal and -shm files from the data folder of the application, then the application displays the correct contents.

The question is:

How can I make the application read the downloaded file without needing to delete the -wal and -shm files? Or how can I make the application generate those files after taking note of the contents in the downloaded file?

I am including the method which copies the database into the data folder.

```
private void downloadMasterDatabase(){
        StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("master database" + "/master_table");
        String masterDbPath = "/data/data/"+ getPackageName() + "/databases/master_table";
        File masterDbFile = new File(masterDbPath);
        pathReference.getFile(masterDbFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "download was successful" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "download was not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You opened your database, and did not close it, prior to downloading the database file. That will not work reliably. Note that this includes having opened the database and then just allowing your app's process to be terminated.

So, do the following:

- Open the database
- Close the database, which should get rid of the `-wal` and `-shm` files automatically
- Confirm that the `-wal` and `-shm` files no longer exist
- Replace the database file with the downloaded copy

> How can I make the application read the downloaded file without needing to delete the -wal and -shm files?

That will not work, sorry.

> Or how can I make the application generate those files after taking note of the contents in the downloaded file?

Have the database be closed, and those files no longer exist, before copying the downloaded database into position and opening it.

FWIW, [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.6/ImportExport) demonstrates backing up and restoring a database. It happens to use local copies (via the Storage Access Framework) rather than a download, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Now after looking into how to close the Room Database instance and checking your sample project, I understand that basically first you get the instance of the Room Database, then check if it is open and then close it if it is open. Though I might be doing something wrong, since I can't seem to be able to close it. I'll go over the steps. 
1) Get database instance `masterDatabase = MasterDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());`
2) Check if the database is open with  `if (masterDatabase.isOpen()){  }`
3) If it is open, call `masterDatabase.close();`

Comment: @EdwardAarma: "I can't seem to be able to close it" -- can you explain a bit more about what you mean by this?

Comment: So going through the steps mentioned in the previous comment, then it should close the instance of the database and with that also remove the -wal and -shm files, but those files remain, which I assume means that the database was not closed.

Comment: @EdwardAarma: How are you looking for those files? Perhaps it is not being updated in the way that you would expect. For example, with Device File Explorer, you need to manually "Synchronize". Beyond that, do you get the same results if you run my sample?

Comment: I now got it to work, thank you very much for your help, this went a long way for me.